# Spring MVC + Jquery Ajax form [Image with json data] Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

From front end we get an image and a form. I generate a formdata object and send it to the backend (Spring boot). The below mentioned error did not occur when the server was **jetty**. Now we have replaced jetty by **embedded tomcat**, hence the error.

**Backend details**

1. Spring boot
2. Server: Embedded tomcat

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONResponse insertUser(@RequestPart(value = "data") @Valid User user, @RequestPart(value = "image" , required = false) @Valid  MultipartFile image) throws Exception {

        try {
            if (user == null) {
                throw new CustomGenericException("Please pass the user details");
            }

            userService.insertUser(user, image);
            jsonResponse.setMessage("success");
            return jsonResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

**Jquery - Ajax:**

```
$("form[name='userForm']").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var entityJson = form2js("userForm",null,false); // js library to get json from form
        var entityJsonStr = JSON.stringify(entityJson); 
        console.log("en" + entityJsonStr);
        var formData = new FormData();
        console.log(formData);
        formData.append("data", new Blob([entityJsonStr], {
                                type : "application/json"  // ** specify that this is JSON**
                            }));        
       formData.append("image", document.getElementById("file-input").files[0]);
        console.log(entityJsonStr);
        $.ajax({
            url:     "/user/insertUser",
            type:    'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data:    formData,
            error: function(xhr,status,err){
                // failure handling
            },
            success: function(response){
                // success handling
            }
        });
```

**Payload:**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryLXPPEinFQ292Daxw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json


------WebKitFormBoundaryLXPPEinFQ292Daxw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

undefined
------WebKitFormBoundaryLXPPEinFQ292Daxw--
```

**Error:**

```
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException"
message: "Required request part 'data' is not present."
path: "/user/insertUser"
status: 400
```

**Maven dependencies**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>    
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>           

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Check if values are being sent in `data` that is `entityJsonStr` and `new Blob[]`

Comment: Data contains Blob[entityJsonStr] not blob and entityJsonStr. The code works just fine in jetty.